# See all subscribed pages to facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-messenger, facebook-messages

I have created a bot that serves few pages.
I can see the pages the I'm their admin under app->messages->settings

Is there a way to see all pages that are subscribed to the bot which I'm not their admin? maybe there is a special API for that?

Comment: I would guess not, though I'm not sure. How did you manage to get subscriptions that aren't owned by you? Regardless, you could keep track of the bot ID for each page, since it's in the information the bot gets. Unfortunately this would only tell you the number and not the actual pages. You could make a new verification token and have all the sub-pages now need to be done under your administration. IDK though, not sure exactly how you got there and what you're trying to do / need this for.

Comment: Actually I think you might need to change your webhook address now that I think about it. I'm guessing not owning a subscription is not a safe way to do this, so there probably isn't a way to see all subscribed pages that you don't admin.

Comment: Thanks @user2322082 There is no problem to get pages that you don not own to subscribe to the bot, and I can absolutely track these pages myself..

but i thought maybe there is a nice UI for it (just like for the pages I do own) or get an option to do it via an API. please let me know if you have any clue.

Comment: It's weird but looks impossible to do so. So you may have an app and doesn't see that some Pages are using it (its bot via webhook)